# Change color of one char in spyder editor

Tags: colors, spyder, systemcolors

It's my first question in stackoverflow hope I'm making it right!

I'm using Spyder 4.1.5 with python 3.8.5 and IPython 7.19.0.
Let's say i want to change the color of the comma character "," in the editor, mi idea is to make it more visible to ease the reading while i'm programing. Is there a way to do that?

I've searched a little but not found any answer.

Thank you all in advance!
Sorry for my potato english!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Unfortunately, that's not possible in Spyder, sorry.